# Django Custom User Model Admin

Tags: django

In a simple self-training using Django, I'm facing the following problem:
1- I've written a custom user model with two extra fields: phone
2- I've created a custom admin using custom forms
3- In settings: added AUTH_USER_MODEL = "accounts.CustomUser" where accounts is the app name

1- In admin panel, when trying to add a new user, it doesn't display any of the extra fields and this is a problem, also in the case of editing an existing user.
2- In admin: the last statement is: admin.site.register(CustomUser, CustomUserAdmin)
but if i replace it with: admin.site.register(CustomUser), every thing is well and it executed as expected

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kF5tJ.png)
[[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9jfo.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgh3r.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXrK4.png)

Answer (score 0):

first off perhaps just paste the code instead of putting it in a image and sending it that way

anyways from the django docs it seems that you have to unregister the user model from the site first, and than add your own customized one
[django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model)

```
# Re-register UserAdmin
admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

however im not that familiar with customizing the admin page in django
but if what i stated didnt solve your issue perhaps the syntax of your
CustomUserAdmin is wrong
make sure of it by looking at the docs

Comment: It doesn't work, and there is no syntax error and this code is copied from a tutorial